# Selenium (Python) - Changing Proxy During Runitime?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I managed to use a proxy server with selenium for chrome using the code below:

```
chromedriver = "C:/Seltests/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=141.0.175.141:443')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

However, I would like to know if it is possible to change that proxy to a new one during run-time. Or if there is any other way of doing this so it allows me to. I'm thinking that using the code above I would have to have the browser close then re-open to start a new session and use another proxy? Please help :)

Comment: I'm trying to change the proxy to a different one whenever I need to in my script. Without having to restart the script.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to re-launch the browser instance in order to achieve this. Wherever you want to change the proxy insert the following code:

```
driver.quit()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=<new proxy>')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

This will close the current browser and launch a new one with the new proxy.